# Error while attempting to run 'php artisan queue:work' command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue, jenssegers-mongodb

I am attempting to run the `php artisan queue:work` command, but it's terminating the process and providing me with an error.

> [2024-03-28 10:10:20] local.ERROR: Call to a member function
> beginTransaction() on null {"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
> Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null at
> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:108)

I am using a worker on the server, but that is not my issue. When I custom-try `php artisan queue:work`, it gives an error. I want to run the command and do the job work in Laravel.

Comment: have you configured the queue connection?

Comment: yes i configured that properly

Comment: post the full stack trace